# PHP quotes and double quotes wont display data

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm trying to display a text field in PHP from MSSQL, i've read a ton of stuff and nothing is working, The select statement works in MSSQL, but when I put it in PHP it breaks the PHP Code and the page won't display.
so heres my issue i've got a description field in mssql that will output data like this

```
30" x 60" D/S Banner
```

or

```
Billboard 16 x 60 (17'H x 61'W)  3/3 Pockets
```

or

```
Barbara's Mesh Banner
```

so when I'm displaying an array of jobs
the jobnumber, Quantity and dates show fine but the description won't display anything
So i tried replacing the qutoes in sql with

```
replace( replace( convert(varchar(max), Description), '"', ''), '''', '') as Description
```

but that breaks my PHP page and nothing displays, but in my MSSQL qry it runs fine.
I've tried from the PHP side using str_replace to no avail.  Any input would be appreciated

my sql statement in PHP

```
$qry = odbc_exec($connection, "SELECT A.CompanyName, TH.OrderNumber, TD.ID AS PartNumber, TD.Description, TD.Quantity, TD.LineItemNumber,
TH.AccountID, TH.OrderCreatedDate, TH.SaleDate, TH.DueDate, InternalNotes, ProductionNotesTemplate
From TransHeader TH
    Join TransDetail TD
        ON TH.OrderNumber = TD.TransHeaderTransNumber
    LEFT JOIN Account A
        ON TH.AccountID = A.ID
WHERE  AccountNumber = '$AccountNumber' " );
```

displaying the array in PHP

```
while(odbc_fetch_array($qry)){

        $OrderNumber        = odbc_result($qry, "OrderNumber");

        $PartNumber         = odbc_result($qry, "PartNumber");

        $QTY            = odbc_result($qry, "Quantity");

        $InternalNotes      = odbc_result($qry, "InternalNotes");
        $Description        = odbc_result($qry, "Description");

        $DueDate        = odbc_result($qry, "DueDate");
        $LineItemNumber     = odbc_result($qry, "LineItemNumber");
        $ProductionNotes    = odbc_result($qry, 'ProductionNotesTemplate')
```

Comment: Displaying the array in PHP

Comment: What does "breaks my PHP page and nothing displays" mean? No char sequence should cause any effect like this.

Comment: It means when i put the replace in the sql code in php the page errors with HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request without the replace code it still will run but nothing will show in the description fields but all the other fields display correctly in the array

Comment: $qry = odbc_exec($connection, "SELECT A.CompanyName, TH.OrderNumber, TD.ID AS PartNumber, TD.Description, TD.Quantity, TD.LineItemNumber,
TH.AccountID, TH.OrderCreatedDate, TH.SaleDate, TH.DueDate, replace( replace( convert(varchar(max), InternalNotes), '"', 'in'), '''', 'ft') as InternalNotes, ProductionNotesTemplate
From TransHeader TH
 Join TransDetail TD
  ON TH.OrderNumber = TD.TransHeaderTransNumber
 LEFT JOIN Account A
  ON TH.AccountID = A.ID
WHERE  AccountNumber = '$AccountNumber' " );

Comment: Turn on error reporting, you have serious problem to solve.

Comment: k, it's the craziest thing, i've done the same thing more or less in Apache and Mysql, this is IIS and MSSQL, and these quotes have been a nightmare.

Comment: How do you output your data? The problem is most likely there. Post the code.

Comment: <td width="200" align="center" class="cellStyle"><?php echo $InternalNotes; ?></td>

Comment: Just looked at this from a server level, I'm not used to working with windows usually Linux and apache, but i just turned magic quotes on, and it started displaying the data. WHAT AM I RISKING BY DOING THAT

Comment: You shouldn't use magic quotes. [Here are some reasons why](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.whynot.php)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php) and use a prepared statement, [binding values](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) to your query, bypassing the entire quote escaping problem altogether?

To learn more about the step-by-step process of using PDO, [Google](https://www.google.com/?q=pdo%20prepared%20statement%20tutorial) is your friend. After a quick glance at the results from the first page, [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) seemed the most promising.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This might be something i have to do it looks interesting, I'm not really that good with PHP and my time frame might doesn't look great for learning something new.  But it might be the route i have to go

Answer (score 0):

In your code, there is no reason why that should happen.

Your replace query fails because of quoting: try the "here-document" syntax to simplify escaping

```
$sql_code = <<<SQL_CODE
```

SELECT A.CompanyName, TH.OrderNumber, TD.ID AS PartNumber, TD.Description, TD.Quantity, TD.LineItemNumber, TH.AccountID, TH.OrderCreatedDate, TH.SaleDate, TH.DueDate, replace( replace( convert(varchar(max), InternalNotes), '"', 'in'), '\'', 'ft') as InternalNotes, ProductionNotesTemplate From TransHeader TH Join TransDetail TD ON TH.OrderNumber = TD.TransHeaderTransNumber LEFT JOIN Account A ON TH.AccountID = A.ID WHERE AccountNumber = '$AccountNumber';
SQL_CODE;

```
$qry = odbc_exec($connection, $sql_code);
```

but the previous error, the fact that without replacing the display is broken, has no explanation unless the field contains something stranger than quotes, or you don't just "output" it (for example: if you tried to add a DOM entity by generating HTML and putting it into Javascript code, then yes, quotes would almost certainly break your page, and possibly display nothing at all. Even if *this* still does not explain a 500 Error).

So try the original query, but output the `InternalNotes` like this:

```
<td><?php print HTMLEntities($InternalNotes); ?></td>
```

and see what is really inside that variable.

Comment: k thats working.  Do you know much about MagicQuotes?  I did turn that on as well, do you know if that's supposed to be on, it was off by default.

Comment: I don't think `MagicQuotes` (which is, if not deprecated, at least *discouraged*) has anything to do with it. The problem is that you're outputting that stuff in some "not-too-compatible" way. I'm betting that you are *not* actually just displaying good ol' plain HTML on a web page :-)

Comment: K this was the stupidest thing, Like it always is. I had two tables table a and table b both had a Description field in it, in my sql code i was only pulling the description in table a so tablea.description, but was omitting tableb.description when i put both table a and table b description fields in my sql query it worked in php, even though with just table a description it was working in my sql query from query analyzer.  It still doesn't make sense but it works now thanks for all your feed back